# Introduction to rigging and animating

Tags: animation, rigging

Hopefully a very simple question.
I'm setting myself a blender challenge a month. This month I'm trying to model and animate a toy dog my children have as seen below[image]

It's very simple with one bone for spine, a bone per leg, bone for tail and bone for neck.

I would like to animate it walking (and then other animations later) but i've found it surprisingly hard to look right and found it hard to find clear videos on the animation part of things:
Any hints on teh following would be great -

1. how to co-ordinate the legs moving in sync that would look like walking
2. how to best then get the whole body to move in time wiht the legs walking
3. are there ways to "short cut": e.g. if i move front right leg forward, the right front leg automatically goes back the same rate?

I'm sorry if all this seems basic or vague, but any ideas on how to easily animate would be gratefully received.

Many thanks
Richard

Comment: 1) You'll be the one who will create coordination, you need to create some keyframes in Pose mode 2) You have 2 methods: a "static" walk cycle (like a treadmill walk) and you'll move the armature forward in Object mode, you'll need a root bone by the way, or a "dynamic" walk and the bones will move forward in Pose mode. 3) You can give a Copy Rotation constraint to a bone but I'm not sure it will work well, it's a bit like your question 1, no? Maybe you should follow some tutorials on walk animations, I think Darrin Lille and Sebastian Lague have made good ones.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look for those videos. surprisingly the videos i've found so far haven't been super useful.   
As for animation, i didn't want to be laboriously changing angles of legs each time and dragging body etc without realising there was a simpler method. It seems like there could be a way to maybe grab spine bone and it automatically rotates legs at a set tempo/angle? e.g if i grab spine in x direction 2 metres, then i can program it to automatically do 4 leg swings?

Comment: I'm not sure that automatizing with some constraints would be the easiest way to do it, but you'll see after several tutorials that it's no so complicated, maybe the most tricky part is the 'static' walk cycle, I've made a tutorial on this but it's in french: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YTUHC2szcQ